# One charger for two devices: Which one should I choose?

Tags: power-supply, netbook, tablet

I have one Acer tablet with the following specs written on the charger:

> Output: 19V 2.15A

Then, I have an Acer NetBook (Aspire One) with the following specs on the charger:

> Output: 19V 1.58A 30W

The plugs seem to be the same. Can I safely use one charger for both devices? If yes, which one? (And why?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the more powerful DC adapter (19v @2.15A = 40 watts) for both, since the Netbook which requires less juice will only draw what it needs from the more powerful one.  This of course depends on if the plug is not only the same size, but has the same positive/negative configuration.

Think of this like using a Universal DC adapter which puts out a Max of 90 watts, with a device that only draws 65 watts.  Same Deal.

Comment: It *shouldn't* be an issue here, considering both products are Acer... but those could also be considered famous last words.

Comment: Then you are good to go.